# Most Reliable String Split Character in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, string, split

What is the best delimiter to use for splitting a string in JavaScript? I've referenced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879860/most-reliable-split-character) related question and I like the idea of using the ASCII BEL character as my delimiter, but I cannot get this to work.

I am inserting the BEL delimiter into my HTML that I'm splitting like so:

```
&#x0007;
```

and I've tried both of the following arguments in JavaScript to split the proceeding string on the BEL character:

```
var values = response.split(String.fromCharCode(7));
```

and

```
var values = response.split('BEL');
```

The 'BEL' in this second line is not simply the letters B E and L surrounded by quotes, it's another representation of the • character (ALT + 7) and that line renders as

```
var values = response.split('•');
```

when I view the JavaScript in-browser.

Neither of these are working, so if anyone has any reliable JavaScript string-splitting practices that don't require the overhead of string-sanitizing or can get the above method to work, please let me know!

Comment: I'd say it's the comma, used in an array, converted to JSON if you just have to have a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your putting the actual entity string `&#x0007;` into the html, not the actual character •.It just gets rendered as the dot but is still the entity string. For what you are doing now you can split on the whole html entity string

```
"Hello &#x0007; World".split("&#x0007;")
```

You would put the actual character in the string if you wanted to split on it

```
"Hello • World".split("•")
```

Comment: Your first solution works great for me, for some reason the second one doesn't work though.